# Rates of parental burnout for parents with ASD children/disability

Tags: stress, autism, mental-exhaustion

In a [question from Academic SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/135086/handling-disruptive-student-on-the-autism-spectrum/135093#135093), there was a description of parent's of a student on the spectrum refusing to be contacted by the university. I suspect that his parents may be suffering from burn out/mental exhaustion, hence they do not want to be contacted with concerns about their child at university. I am struggling to find studies or reports of parental burnout, especially for parents of children with ASD. Otherwise are there rates for parents with disability in general? The assumptions may be wrong and there are minimal or no impact on the parents?

This 2015 question discusses "[What cognitive processes occur during a mental exhaustion or 'burnout'?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/what-cognitive-processes-occur-during-a-mental-exhaustion-or-burnout)"